# Hide and show select option not working on modal

Tags: javascript, php

The problem is my function hide show is not working when looping data on my modal
what's wrong with my code? anyone can help?

```js
  $('#sectionChooser').change(function() {
    var myID = $(this).val();
    $('.gpanel').each(function() {
      myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    });
  });
```

```css
.gpanel {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #m1 {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?php foreach($produk as $prod) : ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalProd<?= $prod['produk_kode']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="<?= base_url();?>frontendc/addtocart" method="POST" name="cartForm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
              <span class="gpanel btn btn-primary" id="m2">-5%</span>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="pro-1" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                  <img src="<?= base_url().'assets/images/'.$prod['produk_gambar']; ?>" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
              <div class="modal-pro-content">
                <h3>
                  <?= $prod['produk_nama']; ?>
                </h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="produk_kode" value="<?= $prod['produk_kode'];?>">
                <div class="product-price-wrapper">
                  <span class="gpanel" id="m1"><?= "Rp. ".number_format($prod['produk_harga']); ?></span>
                  <span class="gpanel" id="m2"><?= "Rp. ".number_format($prod['produk_harga']-(($prod['produk_harga']*5)/100)); ?></span>
                  <span class="product-price-old gpanel" id="m2"><?= "Rp. ".number_format($prod['produk_harga']); ?></span>
                </div>
                <p>
                  <?= $prod['produk_ket']; ?>
                </p>
                <div class="quick-view-select">
                  <div class="select-option-part">
                    <label>Ukuran</label>
                    <select class="select" name="ukuran" id="sectionChooser">
                      <option value="m1">1 Meter</option>
                      <option value="m2">2 Meter</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
```

when i check the problem is hide & show only working on first modal, but for the next modal is not working.
the problems likes they dont read id aswell. maybe i must put some uniqe id on my javascript?
can someone help me?

[for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adityads/0jn8pmeq/1/)

first modal
[image: first modal]

3rd modal
[image: 3rd modal]

you can see on image 1 with data modal[1](https://jsfiddle.net/adityads/0jn8pmeq/1/) when i change select to '2 papan' the results is discount will be appear on top image also the 'strike' price wil be appear

but on image 2 with modal[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpUY7.png), discount and 'strike' price dont appear on there

Comment: it will be better if you post the html code from `code source` in the browser

Comment: okay already edit my question and add fiddle for code

Comment: I don't understand really what you are looking for but check this https://jsfiddle.net/0jn8pmeq/5/

Comment: add new image on my question pls check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is in foreach loop you will need to have different ids for each block

```
<select class="select sectionChooser" name="ukuran" data-id="<?= $prod['produk_kode']; ?>" id="sectionChooser<?= $prod['produk_kode']; ?>">
```

Here i have added `sectionChooser` class to select dropdown so Change your script as below :

```
$('.select').change(function() {
  var myID = $(this).val();
  var dataID = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('#modalProd'+dataID+' .gpanel').each(function() {
     (myID === $(this).attr('id')) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i change my code with ur code, the results is not working fo all modals. even for first modal it doesn't work

Comment: still same, not working even first modal . maybe u can use my fiddle to test your code. already add fiddle on my question

Comment: `$prod['produk_kode']` seems blank please verify

Comment: try with my update in https://jsfiddle.net/0jn8pmeq/6/ . php variable are empty in js fiddle so please try it in your local

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm already cross check and your answer working fine for me.